# Can someone check my proof that an infinite subset of a countable set is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Thanks in advance.

Definitions: A set is $S$ countable iff there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and S.

Some notable allowed assumptions: Non-empty finite sets of real numbers contain a maximum and a minimum. Non-empty sets of integers that are bounded above contain a maximum, similarly non-empty sets of integers that are bounded below contain a minimum. The natural numbers are not bounded above (Archimedian principle). Induction, strong induction.

This is problem 1.5.1 in "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott.
Problem: Assume $B$ is a countable set. Thus, there exists a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to B$ which is a bijection. Let $A \subseteq B$ be an infinite subset of $B$. Show that $A$ is countable.

My proof:

[image: My proof]

Comment: The preferred definition is that $S$ is countable iff $S$ is a bijective image of $\Bbb N$ or a bijective image of $\{x\in \Bbb N:x<n\}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N. $ That is, countable means "finite or countably infinite". In English this makes "uncountable" synonymous with "not countable".

Comment: Re: Allowed assumptions. The sets referred to should be specified as non-empty. The empty set is finite & bounded, but does not contain a maximum, or anything else either.